# Drop rows before a column value changes the first time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have thousands of pd.Dataframes which look similar to the example `df` below.
I want to remove all rows before the value in the column `le` changes the first time, except for the last row with the duplicate value. E.g., I want to drop the first two rows in `df` here. However, I do not find a universal solutions for this I can use for all dataframes I have.

```
id     no     parent  le               dia
10     1           1  9.18359371679495  112.963635499912           
10     1           1  9.18359371679495  102.261060580237            
10     1           1  9.18359371679495  102.261060580237        
10     1           1   46.531309334225  75.1405324759379           
10     1           1   148.45737705256  68.9880315000758           
10     1           1  266.349709386555  68.9880315000758
10     1           1   352.40977395104  68.9880315000758        
10     1           1   352.40977395104  68.9880315000758       
10     1           1   352.40977395104  68.9880315000758 
...
```

I tried to approach this with deleting duplicates, but duplicates later then the first change should be kept.
The final `df` should look like this:

```
id     no     parent  le                dia
10     1           1  9.18359371679495  102.261060580237        
10     1           1   46.531309334225  75.1405324759379           
10     1           1   148.45737705256  68.9880315000758           
10     1           1  266.349709386555  68.9880315000758
10     1           1   352.40977395104  68.9880315000758        
10     1           1   352.40977395104  68.9880315000758       
10     1           1   352.40977395104  68.9880315000758            
...
```

Comment: maybe [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep='last'`?

Comment: This is not working if there are several duplicates and I only want to delete the first duplicates and ignore every other duplicates in lower rows

Comment: yes, I updated the sample data

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df.drop_duplicates('le', keep='last')

id  no      parent  le          dia
10  1       1       9.183594    102.261061
10  1       1       46.531309   75.140532
10  1       1       148.457377  68.988032
10  1       1       266.349709  68.988032
```

Comment: This does not work if there are more duplictes that I do not want to remove. I only want to remove the duplicated until the first "not duplicate" and keep the last of these duplicates.

Comment: you can give another example so I can understand more

Comment: I updated the example

Comment: on your updated output, only the 2 first rows are removed, why ? what about the other duplicated? you need to explain more. you need to remove only the first seen duplicate ?

Comment: As written above in the original post I want to drop only the rows until the value in le changes the first time and keep the last duplicate as well. So I want to remove only the first seen duplicates